# How exactly do I compile my Java into a JAR file?

Tags: java, jar

So I'm trying to compile my game for my Object-Oriented Programming class into a `jar` file so it can be ran with `java -jar javacoffeeadventure.jar`.

My folder structure for a folder with `java` files removed looks like this:

```
audiomanager/
commandinterpreter/
gamemanager/
io/
logic/
META-INF/
player/
resources/
rooms/
main.class
```

Everything is packaged under `javacoffeeadventure`. For example, the `main` file is `javacoffeeadventure.main`. The `META-INF` folder contains one `MANIFEST.MF` file that I tried to edit and make the `jar` invoke `main.class`'s `main()` method:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.8.0_60 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: javacoffeeadventure.main
```

I know I use `jar` to compile into a `jar` file, but how would I use that command to create a `jar` file that is able to begin with `javacoffeeadventure.main`? Is my manifest wrong?

*as a slight by-the-way, jar puns are funny to me if you guys have any. :)*

Comment: I'd use Eclipse to build a .jar file. No pun intended.

Comment: you have a class called main? :) that is funny

Comment: Keeping naming conventions aside, I think your MANIFEST.MF should have the following line "Main-Class: main"

Comment: @nicomp Wouldn't I have to remake the thing so it's an Eclipse project?

Comment: google for self executing jar

Comment: @Mil4n What sorta name did you want me to use for the class that just has a `main` method?

Comment: The main problem is you actually need `javacoffeeadventure` on the path so that the `jar` command can assign the right path to them in the Jar file.  Most of these directories should be in `java/javacoffeeadventure`, except for the `META-INF` directory.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE , not really. You could create an empty Java project and copy your directory structure into the project folder and then refresh the project. If you're coding from the command line then it's time to learn an IDE anyway. IHMO, and I teach Java.

Comment: No offense intended - I don't know really - because it seems that you skipped few steps in java like naming classes and package convention... but that aside you didn't show us how you tried to build your jar file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, the following has worked, but if you utilize it, you may need to adapt your directory structure.

First, your folder structure needs to be of the form 'containing_folder.com.example.package', where your classes are in the 'package' folder.  You need to then place your manifest.mf file in the uppermost directory ('folder').  The manifest file should be as follows:

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 Main-Class: com/example/package/javacoffeeadventure
```

including a carriage return after the second line.

From the initial folder compile with the following command:

```
jar cmvf manifest.mf javacoffeeadventure.jar com/example/package/*.class
```

making sure that beforehand you've compiled the classes in your package (use *.java)

Hope this helps.